# Adding nodes to a Polygon with FME

Tags: fme-form

I have a vector file with a single, simple polygon (perhaps 10 nodes). I want to add more nodes to this polygon, retaining the original shape.

The obvious question here is *'why would you want to do that?'*. It solves an issue further down stream in the process. It's a hack.

Is that possible in FME? Can you read in a vector file, add nodes to it, and write it out again? Which transformer might you use to achieve that?

Comment: The [Densifier](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/FME_Transformers.htm#Transformers/densifier.htm)?

Comment: I think part of your problem is terminology -- polygons have vertices, not nodes (networks have nodes where lines are linked).  A search on "densify" or "vertex densification" might address your issue.

Comment: Cheers Vince, helping solve this problem and doubtless preventing many future problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, the transformer you're after is the [Densifier](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/FME_Transformers.htm#Transformers/densifier.htm).

From the help:

> Adds vertices to each feature by interpolating new coordinates at fixed intervals.

You have the option to make the vertices evenly spaced or at a defined interval.

Of course, as mKurowsKi points out, there are many ways to do this in FME.

Answer (score 1):

As is always the case with FME, there are many ways to accomplish this task.

Here is one way that centers around Iterative Snipper (available from the FME Store):[image]